# constant for HTTP GET, POST, PUT on JDK or android SDK

Tags: java, android

Are there any enum or constants for HTTP GET, POST, PUT for android?

As far as my searching, JAVA EE or spring has that constants. but failed to find these on Android.

I need to make my own enum for HTTP as below if not exist in android.

```
enum RequestMethod {
  GET, POST, PUT, ...;
}
```

Comment: You can find them here com.android.volley.Request.Method.#

Comment: Maybe you could be more specific why you need the enums you were asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `com.android.volley.Request` class you can find an interface for this purpose:

```
    public interface Method {
    int DEPRECATED_GET_OR_POST = -1;
    int GET = 0;
    int POST = 1;
    int PUT = 2;
    int DELETE = 3;
    int HEAD = 4;
    int OPTIONS = 5;
    int TRACE = 6;
    int PATCH = 7;
}
```

Only thing is that to use this you will have to include `Volley` as a dependency.